# XStream registers only one converter

Tags: java, xml, converters, xstream

On my serialized XML File is only one attribute of my Object saved, although four should be saved. I think this is due to y XStream Object registering only one converter, although he should register four.

My Converters are all functioning individually. I tested them one by one.

My XML File:

```
<object-stream>
  <model.Product>13</model.Product>
</object-stream>
```

My Product class which should be saved:

```
public class Product implements Externalizable, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8437751114305532162L;


    @XStreamConverter(converter.NameConverter.class)
    private  SimpleStringProperty name;

    @XStreamConverter(converter.PriceConverter.class)
    private  SimpleDoubleProperty price;

    @XStreamConverter(converter.CountConverter.class)
    private  SimpleIntegerProperty quantity;

    @XStreamConverter(converter.IDConverter.class)
    private long id;

    public Product(String name, int quantity, double price, long id)
    {
        this.name=new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.quantity=new SimpleIntegerProperty(quantity);
        this.price=new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
        this.id=id;

//Getter and Setter and implentation of Externalizable
```

My XStream class

```
XStream xstream;
ObjectInputStream ois;
ObjectOutputStream oos;

@Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (oos != null) {
            oos.close();
        }
        if (ois != null) {
            ois.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void writeObject(Product obj) throws IOException {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void open(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
        xstream = createXStream(model.Product.class);
        converter.ConverterManager con=new ConverterManager();
        con.registerAllConverters(xstream);

        if (input != null) {
            if (input.available() > 0) {
                ois = xstream.createObjectInputStream(input);
            }
        }
        if (output != null) {
            oos = xstream.createObjectOutputStream(output);
        }
    }

}
```

My ConverterManager:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class ConverterManager {
    public void registerAllConverters(XStream xstream)
    {
        xstream.aliasAttribute("Product Price", "price");
        xstream.registerConverter(new PriceConverter());

        xstream.aliasAttribute("Product ID", "id");
        xstream.registerConverter(new IDConverter());

        xstream.aliasAttribute("Product Name", "name");
        xstream.registerConverter(new NameConverter());

        xstream.aliasAttribute("Product quantity", "quantity");
        xstream.registerConverter(new CountConverter());


    }

}
```

My writeObject, open and close methods are called from this method from another class:

```
private void saveModel() {

    XStreamStrategy s=new XStreamStrategy(); 
    try {
        s.open(getFilePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(fpt.com.Product p: model)
    {
        try {
            s.writeObject(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    try {

        s.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```